# Removing JVM properties from WAS 7 from the filesystem

Tags: jvm, websphere-7

I recently was modifying some of my server properties in Rational Application Developer to try and increase the memory of my JVM on startup.  I forgot to take a backup before doing this, and by adding in an incorrect JVM variable, it seems I have broke my server in an unworking state.  Whenever I try and startup my server to do any configuration changes, the JVM refuses to start with invalid params being passed in.

Is there a way to reset any JVM changes for WebSpehere Application Server v7.0 through the filesystem, or a way to do it without needing the server running already?  I have been looking around in the wasProfile hoping to stumble onto a file where my settings ultimately live, but have had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to write a wsadmin script to view/adjust the JVM options, but if you're on a non-z/OS platform, the fastest way to get back to working is probably to edit `PROFILE_HOME/config/cells/CELL/nodes/NODE/servers/SERVER/server.xml`; the JVM settings are typically written at the very end.

Comment: The `server.xml` was exactly what I needed.  I knew those settings lived in the filesystem somewhere for me to edit.  Thanks again!

Comment: I should have mentioned that manually editing these files isn't guaranteed to work since the systems management code sometimes has save hooks that implement extra logic (e.g., copying the setting to other files potentially in different formats), and those can only be called if you're using wsadmin, admin console, etc.  That said, it often will work, and if your server won't start, it can be useful to know where the settings are.